# ffmpeg を開こうと思っても一瞬で開いても閉じまう

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpegを開こうと思っても一瞬で開いて閉じます。一からやり直したほうがいいですか。その場合もう泣き寝入りしかありません。
テラテイルでも質問してみましたが、パスは通ってるとの指摘を受けました。

以下はコマンドプロンプトによる結果です。

```
C:\Users\mizun>ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version n5.0-4-g911d7f167c-20220322 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 11.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.24.0.533_681aaef)
configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --disable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --disable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --disable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --disable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --disable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --disable-libx264 --disable-libx265 --disable-libxavs2 --disable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20220322
libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100

C:\Users\mizun>
```

Answer (score 5):

ffmpeg は **コマンドで動作する** ツールなので GUI は用意されていません。
エクスプローラからダブルクリックしても、例えばブラウザのような画面が表示されるわけではありません。

あなたがコマンドプロンプトで `ffmpeg -version` と実行したように、コマンドで実行する必要があります。

例:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -b:v 64k -bufsize 64k output.avi
```

**参考:**
[ffmpeg Documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)